# What is .NET Runtime Identifier for Windows 11

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-6.0, windows-11, self-contained

As you all know .NET let's us publish self-contained applications targeting a specific platform by mentioning the Runtime Identifier at the time of publish. For those of you who are not aware what a self-contained application is, more about it is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#publish-self-contained) -

In the past I have successfully published such applications targeting windows 7, 8.1, 10 using the Runtime Identifiers mentioned in the [.NET RID catalog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog)

Question is, what is the RID for publishing an application targeting windows 11 ?

Things I tried -

- Tried using win11-x64 as this is line with existing windows x64 RIDs. But build failed with error "Runtime identifier not recognized"
- Installed latest version of .NET 6 hoping this will solve the issue but it didn't.
- Searched through Microsoft docs and github issue list but couldn't find anything to come to the conclusion whether windows 11 support is there or not. Or if it's a work in progress.
- Found [latest and complete version of RIDs](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms/src/runtime.json) has no mention of windows 11.
- Submitted an issue to update the docs - https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/28885. But not sure when this will get attention.

Please help me with any information you have regarding this.

Comment: Per [this comment](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/62755#issuecomment-1013354264) it sounds like these haven't been added and won't be added given there's no real difference to win10.

Comment: @CharlesMager heh, I remember when Microsoft said [there will be no new OS after Windows 10](https://www.cnbc.com/2021/06/11/why-microsoft-is-releasing-a-new-version-of-windows.html).  _TPM2_ anyone?

Comment: @CharlesMager, thank you for pointing out to the discussion. To avoid confusion, there should be some mention of this in the official document. I will add that as a comment in the issue I raised. Please put your comment in the answer box so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been discussed [elsewhere on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/62755#issuecomment-1013354264).

The answer at present appears to be that these have not been added and will not be added given there is little or no difference between Windows 10 and Windows 11 at an API level.